# How to deal with Future in Vert.x

Tags: java, future, vert.x

I am pretty new to Vertx Framework. So I am a little lost in using Asynchronous programming. My question is how to deal with future if I want to just compute the results instead of return another future.

```
class example {
private computedData;
public Future<Void> process() {
      Future<T> search = OperationFromDataBase();
      Future<Void> finalFuture = search.onComplete(re -> {
            computeWithresult();
            for (;computeResult;) {
                getOtherFuturesFromDataBase()
                future1.oncomplete(..);
                future2.oncomplete(..);
                ...
                futurei.oncomplete(..);
            }).mapEmpty();
     return finalFuture;
 }
 };
```

I searched about practices on these future stuff but I don't understand pretty well. I don't know if this is the correct practice though. What I want to do is after search future ends I can create other futures based on its results and I want to have the final future notify other functions to return a response from the object if all futures it contains are finished. Did I make some mistakes like if I call the finalFuture.oncomplete on other functions while future1..i is not finished? What should I do to solve this?

Comment: You don't have to return a `Future`. If you don't care about the operation result it can be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

If finalFuture is dependent on the results of future1..future n, I would recommend looking at CompositeFutures. [Composite Future Docs Here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_future_coordination)

CompositeFutures.all waits for all futures to succeed, or fails if one fails.

If you generate the futures before initialising the CompositeFuture, you can then individually access the results for that future later on.

```
Future f1 = getX()
Future f2 = getY()
Future f3 = getZ()

CompositeFuture cf = CompositeFuture.all([f1,f2,f3])

cf.onComplete(ar -> {
    //Check Succeeds
    //DO FURTHER PROCESSING
})
```

I hope I've understood correctly and this helps.